# AutoValues from Session.get()

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a simple schema in other to use `autoform` in `meteor`. I am having problem with this field in my Schema. When I submit the form it does nothing. How can I set and insert the value of my `id_master` in the array with autoValues through the `Session.get()`?

```
master_id: {
    type: [String],
    label: "id_master",
    autoValue: function(){
    if( this.isInsert ) {
        var x =Session.get('id_master'); 
        console.log(x);//returns the value of id_master
       return [x]
        }
    }, 
    autoform:{
        type: "hidden"
    }

},
```

---

I'm using autoForm :

```
{{> quickForm collection="Hitos" id="insertHitosForm" type="insert" class="new-hito-form"}}
```

And I have allowed Inserting :

```
Hitos.allow({
        insert: function(userId, doc){
            //you are allowed to insert Hitos if userid exist
            return !!userId;

        }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for your form and for handling the form submission?

Comment: @NFab By using autoForm, the submit is handled automatically when the Insert function is allowed. 
The only problem is that I don't know how to get the _id stored in Session as one of my autoValues _id array.  NOTE: I was able to retrieve the _id just before the autoValues field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you shouldn't need to, but have you tried using `clean()`?

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  insertHitosForm: {
    onSubmit: function (doc) {
      Hitos.clean(doc);
      console.log("Hitos doc with auto values", doc);
      this.done();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was an issue earlier as well. Refer to [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/900) post

Try if something like this would work for you as well.

```
AutoForm.hooks({
     insertHitosForm:{
        before: {
          insert: function(doc) {
               doc.master_id = [Session.get('active_project')]
               return doc;
               }
        }
   }
});
```